# stencil bundle command is not working when i add new js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigcommerce

I have added multiple js files in my theme (stencil-cli) and when I run `stencil bundle` command, js errors get thrown.

I have tried deleting `appdata/roaming/npm/node_module`, but that hasn't resolved the issue.

These are the types of error being thrown:

```
 keyword-spacing
  13:7511  error    'jQuery' is not defined
no-undef
  13:7517  error    A space is required after ','
comma-spacing
  13:7524  error    A space is required after ','
comma-spacing
 ✖ 1830 problems (1728 errors, 102 warnings)

C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\ste
ncil-bundle.js:253
            throw err;
            ^
Error: Please fix the above Javascript errors.
    at runLintTask (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce
\stencil-cli\lib\bundle-validator.js:268:18)
    at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\
node_modules\async\lib\async.js:718:13
    at Immediate.iterate [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:262:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

C:\Users\admin\stencil>
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps from https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/js-101#assetsjsdir ?

Comment: yes i have add js file in asset/js/jpages.js and then after run stencil bundle

Comment: Hi i have follow step as a BC document, And i hope you guide. I am waiting your positive reply

Comment: have you also mapped to those modules?

Comment: I have a just add my js in this path asset/js/jpages.js, And really i am totaly confused in this page ( https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/js-101#assetsjsdir ) please gude me how can i add new js and sorry to say my english is weak so please guide me step by step, I have found this issue last 15 day but i can't found perfect solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. If you did not find any answer then I have some suggestions for you. I had same errors when I run stencil bundle command after editing js file.

- Please give trailing space when you use operators like : '=', and also between if and () when you use if statement,
- just follow the line and suggestions which are given in error. you will solve it.
- also white space is not allowed, you just make four spaces instead of a tab space.

I am just giving example and suggesting you to follow instruction in error. I hope you will solve you issue.

Comment: Fix it. Thank you Patel bhai! Jay sardar

Comment: @Jaydeep, If you found this answer helpful, then Please mark it true